# How to color plot in R

Tags: r, colors, plot

I have a two dimensional plot. Every point on it has some value (say, `y`) ranging from `0` to `1`. I want to show these values on a plot using colors. For example, if any point has a value less than `0.25` it should be `green`, points having value between `0.25` and `0.5` will be `yellow` and rest be `red`. How to achieve this in `R`.
Following is the code which generates `y` for various points represented by `(i,j)`.

```
library(reldist)
i <- 0
for(i in seq(from=0, to=.8, by=0.1)){
j <- 0
for(j in seq(from=0, to=1, by=0.1)){

a <- evalq( i*(1+i^2-i^2*j)/((1+i)^2*(1+i^2)) )
b <- evalq( i*(1-j)/(1+i) )
c <- evalq( ((1-j)/(1+i))-i*(1+i^2-i^2*j)/((1+i)^2*(1+i^2)) )

x <- c(a,b,c)
y <- gini(x) # i want to plot y
print(y)

}
}
```

Comment: If you want to plot your data as lines rather than points, you can use the `clplot` tool in `plotrix` (disclaimer - I wrote that tool).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
plot(y , col = ifelse(y < 0.25 , 'green', ifelse( y < 0.5 , 'yellow' , 'red')))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new variable that indexes the colors you want using the `cut()` function.  For example,

```
# I created an example i, j, and y rather than using your code for simplicity
df <- expand.grid(i=seq(0, 0.8, 0.1), j=seq(0, 1, 0.1))
y <- runif(dim(df)[1])

# define the colors you want
mycol <- c("green", "yellow", "red")

# define a color index based on y using the breaks you want
yindex <- cut(y, c(0, 0.25, 0.5, 1), labels=FALSE)

# scatterplot using the specified colors
plot(df$i, df$j, col=mycol[yindex])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `outer` to get the result as a matrix. It's easier than a `for` loop.

```
i <- seq(from=0, to=.8, by=0.1)
j <- seq(from=0, to=0.9, by=0.1)

res <- outer(i,j,FUN=Vectorize(function(i,j) {
  require(reldist)
  a <-  i*(1+i^2-i^2*j)/((1+i)^2*(1+i^2)) 
  b <-  i*(1-j)/(1+i) 
  c <-  ((1-j)/(1+i))-i*(1+i^2-i^2*j)/((1+i)^2*(1+i^2))
  gini(c(a,b,c))
})
)
```

Use `image` for plotting:

```
image(res, breaks = c(-1000,.25,.5,1000),col = c("green","yellow","red"),
      axes=FALSE,xlab="i",ylab="j")
axis(1, at = seq(0,1,length.out=length(i),labels=i)
axis(2, at = seq(0,1,length.out=length(j),labels=j)
```

[image]